# How to convert .flv to .m4v files through FFmpeg

Tags: linux, php, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I want to convert FLV files to M4V files. What is the `exec` (PHP) Linux code for this conversion?

Comment: There is a great blog post about ffmpeg.  Everything you need is in there (and more). http://blog.superuser.com/2012/02/24/ffmpeg-the-ultimate-video-and-audio-manipulation-tool/

Answer (score 2):

In the most simple case:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -an -c:v copy output.m4v
```

This will copy the raw video stream, discard audio, and change the container.

Just wrap this in your PHP `exec` line as you need it. For example:

```
<? exec("ffmpeg -y -i $infile -an -c:v copy $outfile"); ?>
```

Don't forget to update FFmpeg to the latest version depending on your operating system. And, as @soandos mentioned, check out my blog post on that subject: [FFmpeg: The ultimate Video and Audio Manipulation Tool - Super User Blog](http://blog.superuser.com/2012/02/24/ffmpeg-the-ultimate-video-and-audio-manipulation-tool/)